# How to include an image in the header of a blogdown post

Tags: r, blogdown

I am using the Academic Hugo Theme to build a website in R.

I have created a blog post using an RMarkdown file. If I'm interested in inserting a picture in the header of the post, which path should I save it to within the folder structure and how do I include it in my YAML/markdown code?

My YAML is as follows:

```
---
title: "Do oil prices explain the South African Rand's Performance?"
author: "Tangeni Shatiwa"
date: 2020-06-11T21:13:14-05:00
tags: ["South African Rand", "Brent Crude Oil", "Global Uncertainty","Non-Linear Spline Regression"]
output: html_document
---
```

Ideally, I would like an image to appear underneath the title before the content of my post begins

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible! You can include a file named `featured.jpg` (or `featured.png`) in the folder with your post markdown file.

Then you only adapt the YAML header:

```
---
title: "Do oil prices explain the South African Rand's Performance?"
author: "Tangeni Shatiwa"
date: 2020-06-11T21:13:14-05:00
tags: ["South African Rand", "Brent Crude Oil", "Global Uncertainty","Non-Linear Spline Regression"]
output: html_document
image:
  caption: "Oil can"
  focal_point: "Center"
  alt_text: This is a picture of oil can.
---
```

It's called *featured image* and you can read more options in the [documentation](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/managing-content/#featured-image). It looks e.g. like [this post](https://alison.rbind.io/post/2020-06-02-tidymodels-virtually/) (see [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rbind/apreshill/master/content/post/2020-06-02-tidymodels-virtually/index.md)).